# What is the longest running D&D game with the same players and characters?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

[Bruce Schneier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Schneier), a "celebrity" security specialist in the computer industry, recently had an [AMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit#IAmA_and_AMA) session over at Reddit. In an [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/security/comments/4vs90j/bruce_schneier_ama_live_here_from_13_pm_est/d619t1d) to a question, he made a surprising comment:

> I've been playing D&D with the same people -- same GM, same world, same characters -- since 1981. I was a latecomer to the game, which started in 1978. I believe it's the longest-running D&D game with the original players in the world.

To me, that is really impressive, but I confess that this is a world I know very little about, so I'm turning my question over to the experts - is he right? To summarize:

*What is the longest running game of D&D with the same original players, characters, and GM?*

Keeping with the quote, it does not have to be the same *campaign*, although I'm not sure you can rule that out from his comment - there are no further details given.

Someone asked in a [comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86302/what-is-the-longest-running-dd-game-with-the-same-players-and-characters#comment194584_86302) about the "regularity" I would consider valid. For these time spans (35+ years), I would be happy with at least one session per year, but I'm not sure there has to be a strict rule about that.

Comment: Note that Schneier doesn't say if the group's played the same *version* of *D&D* all this time. Does the interview touch on that?

Comment: @nitsua60 That's a good question, and I thought about that. I could not figure out a good answer. For the time spans we're talking about here, I'd be happy with at least one game per year.

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, it doesn't say. I _guess_ they're playing the same version, since he writes about using the same characters, but maybe there are easy ways to "upgrade" characters between the versions? Seeing how I've never played D&D (we had a popular Swedish ["version"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drakar_och_Demoner) instead), I don't know how different they are.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is impossible to answer. The game the OP quoted may be the longest running but there will never be any way to tell if there isn't a longer one that we don't know about. The risk is that we will get a series of answers along the lines of "this one is longer" with no way to verify and no end in sight.

Comment: @DaleM I definitely see your point, but considering that the game in question is already 35 years old, 38 if we take into consideration that he "joined late", I think you're exaggerating the "no end in sight".

Comment: @pipe But in the other sense of "impossible to answer", where could anyone find reliable sources of info for it? "i know a guy that said..." "i used to..." "this one time at band camp..." besides, between OD&D (1974), and AD&D 1e (1977), it isn't like a *significantly* longer game is very likely, if any info has ever been recorded about it.

Comment: I wish our original group were still together ... and some of us are ... now in 5e with an OD&D start in 1975 ... but to say that game has been going in the same campaign is not only not true, but 5-10 year gaps between sessions disqualifies us big time.

Comment: @tzxAzrael Answers can come from published articles about "record-long" games. They don't necessarily have to be word-of-mouth. I honestly don't know - hence the question. _If_ there is a longer running session, I expect the players to be somewhat active in at least some gaming community, and they have probably discussed it, and it should have been published _somewhere_.

Comment: @DaleM "unanswerability" doesn't really strike me as a close reason. Just because a question's hard to answer, or it's hard to conceive of *ever* answering, doesn't make it off-topic, unclear, too broad, &c.

Comment: @nitsua60: There's a meaningful difference between "can't ever get an answer (probably)" and "can't ever get an answer anyone can judge or validate by the terms of the question", and unfortunately this is more the latter. If we can't really vote on anything because the set of possible answers is so hard to pin down and so open-ended, what's the point of asking on SE?

Comment: I've been playing since 1978, and still play with some of the same folks. If we updated our original characters to 5e and played one game, would we break that record? The question is too nebulous and can't be definitively answered, only buried in anecdotes.